# Long.parseLong gives java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java

So I've tried a whole bunch of things, but I'm unable to get around this. `id` in my `Service` class is of data type `long`. I've tried to convert `serviceAuth` to long but it throws a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`. How do I fix this?

```
String[] serviceList = getUser.serviceList.split(",");

for(String serviceAuth: serviceList) {
    Long temp = Long.parseLong(serviceAuth.toString());
    Criteria ctr = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Service.class)
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("id",temp));
}
```

`serviceList` looks like this `5,18,19`. It is loaded from a csv file.

When I print the values in the for loop, it looks like this:

```
1
2
14
15
```

Error report:

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:601)
    java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
    org.x.y.gateway.MainController.getUsers(MainController.java:1433)
    org.x.y.gateway.MainController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6e5db2d9.invoke(&lt;generated&gt;)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    org.x.y.gateway.MainController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$149bedb6.getUsers(&lt;generated&gt;)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.x.y.gateway.CrossOriginRequest.doFilter(CrossOriginRequest.java:18)
```

Comment: What's the value you are passing in to parse?

Comment: Give us a sample of `getUser.serviceList` please.

Comment: @geekchic As per java Doc it may not contain parse able String

Comment: Do a System.out.println(serviceAuth) and comment out the rest of the for each code.

Comment: @enlitement I've done so.

Comment: Hard code this for serviceList:   String[] serviceList = new String("1,2,14,15").split(","); See if an error occurs.

Comment: @enlitement Ah, this was such a great idea. Hard coding this gives no error and I get the expected result.

Comment: may be string contain blankspace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that one of the strings created by `split()` is empty or contains whitespace, e.g.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] serviceList = ",15,18,19".split(",");
        for (String serviceAuth : serviceList) {
            Long temp = Long.parseLong(serviceAuth.toString());
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:7)
```

---

**Update: How to fix the problem**

You should do two things:

- Make the split regex more stable against leading and trailing spaces.
- Skip values of `""` in the loop which can still occur at the beginning of the array.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] serviceList = " , 15 , 18 , 19, ".split("[\\s,]+");
        for (String serviceAuth : serviceList) {
            if ("".equals(serviceAuth))
                continue;
            Long temp = Long.parseLong(serviceAuth.toString());
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

```
15
18
19
```

Comment: You're right! For some users (the code here is within a bigger loop), there may be some null values in the `serviceList`. How do I address that?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a fix. But who the heck downvoted my answer which correctly analysed the root cause of the problem?!

Comment: No idea! Definitely wasn't me. But +1 and I'm trying your solution out now Great idea with the regex!

Answer (score 1):

The string you are trying to parse is not a correct long. The exception also shows you which string caused the problem.

Comment: I mean, I know that something's wrong with the string including which line is creating the problem... in this case it's the line with `Long.parseLong()`, but I don't know what that is or how I can fix it.

Comment: Copy and paste the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with your input data. "" means the string is empty. Long cannot parse an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

The String is empty (input string: ""), Try to hardcode it and print the result or provide the inputs here

Comment: Ah! For a few users (the code here is within a bigger loop), there may be some null values.

Comment: @geekchic then add an empty check as well, if the string is empty dont parse it